# How to use Image inside ActionItem/ ActionBar in IOS Nativescript

Tags: ios, angular, nativescript, action

I'm using Image inside ActionItem/ActionBar like code below

```
<ActionBar class="action-bar">
       <ActionItem ios:position="left">
             <Image (tap)="toggle()" src="res://menu"></Image>
       </ActionItem>
       <ActionItem ios:position="right">
             <Image src="res://logo"></Image>
       </ActionItem>
</ActionBar>
```

The problem is: in view show in ActionBar center only first image `src="res://menu"`

I want to show to image, first image in left and second image in right.

Can you ask me any idea how to implement?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can not position a ActionItem at left corner of ActionBar in Android. You must use NavigationButton for that purpose,

```
<ActionBar>
  <NavigationButton icon="res://menu" (tap)="toggle()" />
</ActionBar>
```

For iOS, it should be `ios.position`

```
<ActionBar class="action-bar">
       <ActionItem ios.position="left">
             <Image (tap)="toggle()" src="res://menu"></Image>
       </ActionItem>
       <ActionItem ios.position="right">
             <Image src="res://logo"></Image>
       </ActionItem>
</ActionBar>
```